# How can i add, edit or delete the Codes in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have a question abaut Sharepoint online, I want to creat a modern Website in SharePoint online but the Template for Design is limited. I want to Edit,delete or add my Website's codes in Sharepoint Online. Can somebody tell me, How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom master pages directly is not supported in modern pages currently. You could inject custom CSS on SharePoint modern pages by using SPFx extensions.

Here're some references for you:

[Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages By Using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

[UPDATE: Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages By Using SPFx Application Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/10/29/update-inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-application-extensions/)

There's a [modern script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) you could utilize. Install it, add it to a page then you could add CSS styling through  tags.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: If you find any replies helpful to you, please remember to mark them as answers.